# How can I insert same name data in same table in php?

Tags: php

In my application have a option for added new product in my product list by its name and date wise.When i try to add same product in another date it doesn`t insert.

my table looks like that:

> Date |  Materials_code | Materials_name  | Parts_code | Unit |  Input_qty
>
> > 2019-05-22, 1200    ,  H1    ,         A12  ,       Pcs ,   50
> >         2019-05-21, 1250,     mat     ,        B25   ,   Pcs     ,   50

now I want to insert again H1 (Materials_name) where date and Input_qty is change

> Date |  Materials_code | Materials_name  | Parts_code | Unit |  Input_qty
>
> > 2019-05-25, 1200    ,  H1    ,         A12  ,       Pcs ,   100

and my expected output is

> Date |  Materials_code | Materials_name  | Parts_code | Unit |  Input_qty
>
> > 2019-05-25,    1200    ,  H1    ,         A12  ,    Pcs,   100
> >
> > > 2019-05-22, 1200    ,  H1    ,         A12     Pcs  ,   50
> > >           2019-05-21, 1250,     mat     ,        B25   ,   Pcs    ,   50

HTML:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" name="form1">
                                            <table width="25%" border="0">
                                                <tr> 
                                                    <td>Date</td>
                                                    <td><input type="date" name="date[]" ></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr> 
                                                    <td>Materials Code</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" name="m_code[]"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr> 
                                                    <td>Materials Name</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" name="m_name[]"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr> 
                                                    <td>Parts Code</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" name="parts_code[]"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr> 
                                                    <td>Unit</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" name="unit[]"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr> 
                                                    <td>Qty</td>
                                                    <td><input type="number" name="qty[]"></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr> 
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>    
                                        </form>
```

I try this code..

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {  
    $myDate = $_POST['date'];
    $m_code = $_POST['m_code'];
    $m_name = $_POST['m_name'];
    $parts_code = $_POST['parts_code'];
    $unit = $_POST['unit'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];

      for ($i = 0; $i <= count($m_name); $i++) { 
           $m_code = (!empty($m_code[$i])) ? $m_code[$i] : '';
           $m_name = (!empty($m_name[$i])) ? $m_name[$i] : '';
    $parts_code = (!empty($parts_code[$i])) ? $parts_code[$i] : '';
           $unit = (!empty($unit[$i])) ? $unit[$i] : '';
           $qty = (!empty($qty[$i])) ? $qty[$i] : '';
         $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO input(Date,Materials_code, Materials_name, Parts_code, Unit, Input_qty)VALUES('$myDate','$m_code', '$m_name', '$parts_code', '$unit', '$qty')");
```

using this code show that output:

> Date |  Materials_code | Materials_name  | Parts_code | Unit |  Input_qty
>
> > 2019-05-25,    2   ,  1     ,         1  ,    c,   1
> >
> > > 2019-05-22, 1200    ,  H1    ,         A12     Pcs  ,   50
> > >           2019-05-21, 1250,     mat     ,        B25   ,   Pcs    ,   50

Comment: Without seeing the HTML I would guess that you are using select elements on your page. You have a value set for each item. This value is being sent through not the actual data that you want.

Comment: Why you expecting 25th date. you are inserting 22nd right. or the question is wrong?

Comment: Use parameterized queries. Use error reporting.. Add the table defintions to the question.

Comment: @jeff now i added my html ,please checck and help me out this problem

Comment: @Siddhartha esunuri i also update my qus .please check

Comment: I don't understand. how 25th date comes? while you inserting 22nd. Plz, check your question once.

Comment: @Siddhartha esunuri oh sorry brother.thats my typing mistake

Comment: Is Materials_name field set as unique in MySQL? or primary?

Comment: @Siddhartha esunuri  primary

Comment: Hey, your code is **wide open** to SQL injection attacks.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem.  **You will be hacked** if you haven't been already, not to mention all of the random application errors you'll end up with if your users use quote marks and what not in their text values.

Comment: @FazlulHoqueSawrav the [] after the name indicates that you are sending arrays of data. If you are only sending one piece of information at a time then remove the [] in the names otherwise you need to loop through the data and save each record.

Comment: @jeff yes, I`m sending one piece of information at a time.now where i need to used a loop? in html ?

Comment: @FazlulHoqueSawrav - you don't. Remove the square brackets from the input names and process as before.

Comment: @jeff it doesn`t work. when i enterd a name Mat insert only M when remove the square brackets from input name

Comment: You no longer need the php loop because you are not sending an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write this query in your db phpmyadmin

```
ALTER TABLE input
DROP INDEX Materials_name;
```

To drop primary key use this one -

```
ALTER TABLE input
DROP INDEX `PRIMARY`;
```

Comment: what will happen when i use this?

Comment: @FazlulHoqueSawrav it will remove primary key in the table.

Comment: its work but when i inseted one data its insert 2 data at a time.like:                     
 >   2019-05-25, 1200, H1, A12, Pcs ,80 
 >>   0000-00-00, 2, 1, 1, c, 0

Comment: please give me a final solution

Comment: @FazlulHoqueSawrav make another column primary & unique and then check if it works.